# Unable to understand the code to download file from server uning jsp

Tags: jsp

```
<%
String filename="admin.jsp";
String filepath="c:\\";
respose.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filenmae=\""+filename+"\"");
java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath+filename);
int i;
while((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1)
{
out.write(i);
}
fileInputStream.close();
%>
```

Here is the code but I can't understand the meaning of "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM" and "Content-Disposition","attachment; filenmae=\""+filename+"\""

Comment: Generally respose.setContentType(mimetype); decide mimetype of file,mimetype means which types of data file will be store,like for pdf mimetype will be application/pdf,for text file mimetype will be plain/text.if mimetype is not decide then it will be APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM.mimetype is decide base on extension of file.

Comment: That was really helpful what about setHeader? and Content-Disposition and attachment?

Comment: The Content-Disposition response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally